# Adding hundred of thousands of words to spell check dictionary on Fedora 24

Tags: fedora, spell-checking, dictionary

I would appreciate it if someone shows me how to add words to currently installed Arabic spell-check `dict_ar-3.0.oxt` in Fedora 24. I have my own word list which has been extracted from several Arabic dictionaries. My requirement is to find the text file containing the word list of `dict_ar-3.0.oxt` or the master spelling check dictionary such that I can add the new words.

I checked in `/usr/share/dict/` and found a file named `lunix.words` and another file named `words`. However, it contains only the English words. So, is it possible to add Arabic words to the file `linux.words`?

Comment: you claim you installed `dict_ar`, which means an Arabic dictionary should already be on your system. Run `rpm -ql` to see which files it installs? One of them is likely going to contain the Arabic words. Adding Arabic words to an English dictionary is probably a bad idea...

Comment: Wouter, thanks for your kind comment. The dictionary is installed as a libreoffice extension. When I ran `rpm -ql dict_ar` it returns that the package is not installed. Any ideas?